# How to change the background color of the Main Title in baposter?

Tags: baposter

> Hi, everyone. This is my first question here! I am working on a poster. I was trying to change the main title's color to be: background -- marine blue, text color -- white. I succeeded in changing the main title's text color to white by directly using \textbf{\color{white}{main title}}, but somehow found no way to change the background color. I have tried to change all the color options to see if anything works, but got no luck. Can anyone help me with that? Many thanks!
> [baposter.cls](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bWQO7XpCOpnRV25XfKCNtFtjaUWn7SsG/view?usp=sharing)

```
\documentclass[landscape,archE]{baposter}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{palatino}
\selectcolormodel{RGB}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{reddishyellow}{cmyk}{0,0.22,1.0,0.0}
\definecolor{black}{cmyk}{0,0,0.0,1.0}
\definecolor{DrexelBlue}{HTML}{07294D}
\definecolor{Gray}{HTML}{777675}
\typeout{Poster Starts}
\background{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\draw (current page.north west)+(-2em,2em) node[anchor=north west] {\includegraphics[height=1.1\textheight]{silhouettes_background}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newlength{\leftimgwidth}
\begin{poster}%
% Poster Options
{
% Show grid to help with alignment
grid=false,
columns=5,
% Column spacing
colspacing=1em,
% Color style
bgColorOne=DrexelBlue,
bgColorTwo=white, 
borderColor=Gray,
headerColorOne=Gray,
headerColorTwo=reddishyellow,
headerFontColor=white, 
boxColorOne=white, 
%boxColorTwo=lighteryellow,
% Format of textbox
textborder=none,
textborder=rectangle,
% Format of text header
eyecatcher=false,
headerborder=open,
headerheight=0.15\textheight, %11
headershape=rectangle,
headershade=plain,
headerfont=\Large\textsf, %Sans Serif
boxshade=plain,
background=shadeTB,
linewidth=.5pt
}
% Eye Catcher
{% No eye catcher for this poster. (eyecatcher=no above).
}%If an eye catcher is present, the title is centered between eye-catcher and logo.
% Title
{\sf %Sans Serif
%\bf% Serif
\vspace{.25em}
\textbf{Evaluating the Model}\\}
% Authors
{\sf %Sans Serif
\vspace{.25em}John Smith$^{1}$, Harrison Frank$^{2}$\\ %.25
{\small
$^1$ Doctoral Student,USA\\
$^2$ USA}
}
{
\begin{minipage}[t]{50.0em} %28
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\end{tabular}
\vfill
\end{minipage}
} 
\tikzstyle{light shaded}=[top color=baposterBGtwo!30!white,bottom color=baposterBGone!30!white,shading=axis,shading angle=30]
\setlength{\leftimgwidth}{0.78em+8.0em}
\newcommand{\colouredcircle}[1]{%
\tikz{\useasboundingbox (-0.2em,-0.32em) rectangle(0.2em,0.32em); \draw[draw=black,fill=baposterBGone!80!black!#1!white,line width=0.03em] (0,0) circle(0.18em);}}
\small
\headerbox{Introduction}{name=data,column=0,row=0,span=2}{
\begin{minipage}[l]{1\textwidth}
\end{minipage} 
}
\headerbox{Methods}{name=model,column=0,below=data,span=2}{
\begin{minipage}[l]{1\textwidth}
\end{minipage}
}
\headerbox{Case Study}{name=trends,column=2,row=0,span=3}{
}
\headerbox{Summary}{name=summary,column=2,below=trends,span=3}{
\begin{minipage}[l]{1\textwidth}
\end{minipage}
}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use two letter font commands. They've been obsolete for many many years. See [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361). Also I don't think you meant two write `\textbf{white}{Title}`. Perhaps `\color{white}` inside your title elements is what you had in mind.

Comment: You are right. It is a typo, already fixed it! Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I have these error `! LaTeX Error: File "baposter.cls" not found.`  Where do you find this `baposter` class?

Comment: My bad. I attached the baposter.cls file. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. There is no key for setting the background of the poster title. The process is:

1. Define the `headerheight` with `headerheight=0.10\textheight`. This means that 10% of the height of the poster page will be used to write the poster header.
2. Set the key `background=user`. This means that you are going to define how the poster background will be created using the `baposter` macro, `\background{}`.
3. Write the code to draw and / or fill the background. In this case, you want a different colour for the header. We can do this by writing: `\fill [fill=HeaderBackground] (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-\headerheight] current page.north east);` where `HeaderBackground` defines your choice of colour, and we draw a rectangle equal to the width of the poster and a height equal to `headerheight` (as defined above).

The complete code for drawing the background is:

```
\background{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    %the poster background color (the whole page)
    \fill[fill=PosterBackground] (current page.north west) rectangle 
    (current page.south east); 
    %the header (just the top of the page where the title is written)
    \fill [fill=HeaderBackground] (current page.north west) rectangle 
    ([yshift=-\headerheight] current page.north east); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Doing so produces this result:

[image]

Some other comments. `\headerbox` is a macro that is deprecated and replaced with `\begin{posterbox} ... \end{posterbox}`. The difference is that you cannot include verbatim content in the `\headerbox` macro, whereas because `\begin{posterbox} ... \end{posterbox}` is an environment, you can include verbatim material. If you like grid layout that can be created using `baposter`, you might be interested in the functionality provided by the `poster` library in the `tcolorbox` package. It was modelled on `baposter`, but arguably has even more functionality.

The complete code is:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names}{xcolor} % <-- added
\documentclass[landscape,archE]{baposter}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{palatino}
\selectcolormodel{RGB}
\definecolor{reddishyellow}{cmyk}{0,0.22,1.0,0.0}
\definecolor{black}{cmyk}{0,0,0.0,1.0}
\definecolor{DrexelBlue}{HTML}{07294D}
\definecolor{Gray}{HTML}{777675}
\colorlet{HeaderBackground}{NavyBlue} % <-- added
\colorlet{PosterBackground}{SkyBlue}  % <-- added
\newlength{\leftimgwidth}

\begin{document}

\typeout{Poster Starts}
\background{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    %the poster background color
    \fill[fill=PosterBackground] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east); %% cover the whole poster
    %the header
    \fill [fill=HeaderBackground] (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-\headerheight] current page.north east); % just for the poster header, fill with a different color.
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{poster}%
% Poster Options
{
% Show grid to help with alignment
grid=false,
columns=5,
% Column spacing
colspacing=1em,
% Color style
bgColorOne=DrexelBlue,
bgColorTwo=white,
borderColor=Gray,
headerColorOne=Gray,
headerColorTwo=reddishyellow,
headerFontColor=white,
boxColorOne=white,
%boxColorTwo=lighteryellow,
% Format of textbox
textborder=none,
textborder=rectangle,
% Format of text header
eyecatcher=false,
headerborder=open,
headershape=rectangle,
headershade=plain,
headerfont=\Large\sffamily, %Sans Serif  % <-- \sffamily
boxshade=plain,
%background=shadeTB,                    % <-- omit
background=user, %user or none or plain % <-- added
headerheight=0.10\textheight,           
linewidth=.5pt
}
% Eye Catcher
{% No eye catcher for this poster. (eyecatcher=no above).
}%If an eye catcher is present, the title is centered between eye-catcher and logo.
% Title
{\sffamily\color{white}% %Sans Serif   % <-- \sffamily\color{white}
\vspace{.5em}%
\textbf{Evaluating the Model}%
}
% Authors
{\sffamily\color{white}%              % <-- \sffamily\color{white}
\vspace{.5em}%
John Smith\textsuperscript{1}, Harrison Frank\textsuperscript{2}\par%
{\small%
\textsuperscript{1} Doctoral Student,USA\par
\textsuperscript{2} USA}}
{}% Logo
\begin{posterbox}[name=box1, column=0, span=1]{Header}   % <-- replace headerbox with posterbox
Some text
\end{posterbox}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```